# add value to shipping service

Tags: commerce

I am using flat rate shipping service and I want to add a value to shipping service price, I know drupal commerce  has a rule for this job, `Add an amount to the unit price` , but when I want to complete it  I don't know what is should enter in  **Line item** section ?

I try below one by one

```
commerce-order:commerce-line-items:0
commerce-order:commerce-line-items:1
commerce-order:commerce-line-items:2
commerce-order:commerce-line-items:3
commerce-order:commerce-line-items:4
```

but no one work. exactly what this mean, I want add value to only line item that is shipping type, I search google but didn't get any example or something similar this.

appreciate any lead an suggestion about what I should enter in **line item** ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the component rule for the flat rate. Instead, you'll want to create a shipping pricing rule.

http://youtu.be/trLydGpimD4?t=10m7s

In that video, I show you how to set up a shipping pricing rule that only runs on a particular flat rate service ... I've linked for you to jump to the part of the video that walks you through that.

The two conditions you're looking to add:

Entity has field (it should have the shipping service field)
Data Comparison (the shipping service field should equal whatever flat rate you want to tweak)

Josh